# Javascript ActiveX cant load object

Tags: javascript, activexobject

i cant get my page to work. On loading a page i get error in this line `tscontainer = new ActiveXObject('BDATuner.SystemTuningSpaces');` any ideas why i get this error and how to start my page to work?

I am using IE8.

msvidctl.dll can be found in 2 directories:
C:\WINDOWS\system32

C:\WINDOWS\RegisteredPackages{AA936DF4-2B08-4B1F-B071-72192E287704}

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT language=Javascript>


var tscontainer, ts, tr, locator;

function window_onload(){
    tscontainer = new ActiveXObject('BDATuner.SystemTuningSpaces');
    ts = tscontainer('DVB-T');
    //ts = tscontainer('Nero DVBT Tuning Space');
    //ts = tscontainer('KWORLD_DVBT');
    tr = ts.CreateTuneRequest();
    locator = new ActiveXObject('BDATuner.DVBTLocator');
    tr.SID = -1;
    tr.TSID = -1;
    tr.ONID = -1;
    locator.Bandwidth = 8;
    locator.CarrierFrequency = 762000;
    tr.Locator = locator;
    //MSVidCtl.MaintainAspectRatio = 'True';
    MSVidCtl.View(tr);
    MSVidCtl.Run();
    currentchannel.value = tr.Locator.CarrierFrequency;
}

function channel_enter(){
    tr.Locator.CarrierFrequency = currentchannel.value;
    MSVidCtl.View(tr);
    currentchannel.value = tr.Locator.CarrierFrequency;
}


</Script>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#000001" TEXT="#FFFFFF" LINK="#FCCB7A" VLINK="#551A8B" ALINK="#EE0000" onLoad="window_onload()">
<CENTER>
<OBJECT ID="MSVidCtl" CLASSID="CLSID:B0EDF163-910A-11D2-B632-00C04F79498E" Width="800" Height="600"></OBJECT>
<HR><B>FREQUENCY: </B><INPUT TYPE="text" id=currentchannel maxlength=7 SIZE=7>
<INPUT id=enter type=button value="APPLY" onClick="channel_enter()">
</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should download from web.

> msvidctl.dll

or you can download the latest DirectX since this file use is related to functions like games and advanced graphics.

Comment: But prefer downloading DirectX latest version.

Comment: thank you, but it didn't helped, download of newest msvidctl.dll and newest directx install.